# How can I access the index of the clicked item?

Tags: javascript, html, function, foreach

I'm building a shop section for a school project. It works like a gallery: when clicking on an card, a new display opens up with fullscreen info about the product: img, product title, price... I've managed to match the image of the fullscreen display to the one clicked (you won't see the images since it's a relative URL).

Now I need to match the rest of the info.

```
const miniaturas = document.querySelectorAll(".galeria a");
const modal = document.querySelector(".modal");
const imgModal = document.querySelector(".modal img");
const plantNames = document.querySelectorAll(".galeria h3")
const plantNameModal = document.querySelector(".modal h3");

miniaturas.forEach(function(miniatura){
    miniatura.addEventListener("click", function(evento){
        evento.preventDefault();
        imgModal.setAttribute("src",miniatura.getAttribute("href"));
        modal.classList.add("visible");

        for(i = 0; i < miniaturas.length; i++){
            plantNameModal.innerHTML = plantNames[i].innerHTML;
        }
    })
})

modal.addEventListener("click", function(){
    modal.classList.remove("visible");
})
```

I don't know how to get the innerHTML via each item's index. I've tried using a for loop and the parameter "miniatura" from the function. [CodePen here.](https://codepen.io/gabmartin/pen/BaPZxqw)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the index of each `miniatura` as the second argument to the handler function you pass to the `forEach`. You have access to this index within the body of the `addEventListener`, as in:

```
miniaturas.forEach(function(miniatura, index){
    miniatura.addEventListener("click", function(evento){
        evento.preventDefault();
        imgModal.setAttribute("src",miniatura.getAttribute("href"));
        modal.classList.add("visible");
      
        // instead of for loop, use `index` to access
        // the corresponding elements in the arrays:
        plantNameModal.innerHTML = plantNames[index].innerHTML;
    })
});
```

I have [forked](https://codepen.io/76484/pen/MWBozJj) your Pen.